# Return data from multiple sheets using vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I would like a reference `sheet1("Index")` having `A:A (ID#)` and `B:B` `(Sheetname)`. This project has several sheets referenced on `sheet1` `B:B`

For simplicity, `sheet1` `B:B` will reference `sheet2("Assets")` or `sheet3("Locations")`. I want to return data from `sheet2` or `sheet3` depending on `sheet1` `B:B` reference.

`Sheet2("Assets")` has `A:A` `(ID#)`, `B:B` (Description), `C:C` more info and so on. `Sheet3("Locations")` has similar data as `Sheet2`.

Using vlookup I would like `sheet1` `B:B` to direct `vlookup` to either `sheet2` or `sheet3`.

Normally I would use vlookup table array as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Assets!$B:$C,2,FALSE) or

=VLOOKUP(A2,Locations!$B:$C,2,FALSE)
```

On `sheet1` I've unsuccessfully tried

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,B2 & !$B:$C,2,FALSE)
```

How can I use `sheet1` `vlookup` to return data found on multiple sheets?

Another question, is there a simpler way to replace `vlookup` data errors with blank cell. This is the formula I use:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Assets!$B:$C,2,FALSE),"")<>"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Assets!$B:$C,2,FALSE),""),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

In C2 of your reference sheet, please try something like:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT($B2&"!A:D"),COLUMN()-1,0)
```

copied across and down to suit.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance. Unfortunately this phase of the data migration project is temporarily on hold. I will need to handle another issue when we start back on task. Our Toad extract of work order records exceed 1,200,00 excel records, the extract writes at least 5-6 spreadsheets, i.e. WORKORDER1, WORKORDER2, etc. Using above info sheet 1 B:B would tell vlookup the sheet to find ID#, with B:B WORKORDER value I need to tell vlookup to look at 1st WORKORDER1 than WORKORDER2, etc. Can someone assist me with a vlookup statement to do this.